# Storing functions in data structure to later find and call them

Tags: c++, data-structures, heap-memory, unordered-map

I am thinking to create a program to store functions in an unoredered map. Is it possible to find them by their key and call them? I also want to use that as header file in other modules. Will it address same memory address location or generate new memory every time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mean

```
std::unordered_map<some_key_type, std::function<Output(Input)>> functions;
// ...
functions[some_value](some_input);
```

?

If you do, see related doc:

- [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)
- [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Comment: just like that  YSC

Comment: @ShubhamJangam note that this requires all functions to have the same parameter type and same return type. If thats not the case, it is still possible just more painful

Comment: @tobi303 That would be a good second answer. (and my 100th vote do get the sportmanship badge :)

Comment: But you didnt ans my second question. ..... if I use that file as header in other files will that create multiple copies in memories ? @YSC

Comment: @ShubhamJangam one question per question, this is what is expected on SO. You should ask another question with a [mcve], because the answer would depend on it.

Comment: @YSC Can you please check out following issue

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

int add(int a, int b)
{
       return a+b;
}
int main()
{
       unordered_map<int , function<int(int,int) >> umap ;
       //umap[1](5,10);

}
**
 output :
  std : bad function call

enter code here
**
I want to map that function attibute in value section to int add function 
I am unable to map it or how I can write the 'values' function body
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't assigned any function to key 1 of umap.

```
umap.insert(make_pair(1, add));
```

This will do the trick.

Comment: there is no function like put

Comment: dont give parameters to function..just do (1, add)

Comment: or umap.insert({1, add});

Comment: how to call these functions and store ans

Comment: THANKS !! DONE!!